# Use HTML form to save Image to SQL Server 2012

Tags: html, node.js, sql-server, forms, express

I use npm express, body-parser, and mssql in Node JS and I'm trying to find a way to create a form, similar to this:

```
            <form action="/" method="POST">


                Id<input class="form-control" type="number" step=any name="id" placeholder="id">

                <br>

                Image
                <input class="form" type="file" name="image"> 

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">metalo!</button>
            </form>
```

that will allow me to save a picture with its id in SQL server 2012.

For the post request I'm doing the following:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){

     //var query = `INSERT INTO myimages (id) VALUES ('${req.body.id}')`;
     var query = `INSERT INTO myimages VALUES ('${req.body.id}',(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'${req.body.image}', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1))`;
                //console.log(query)
     executeQuery (res, query); 

})
```

The error message I get is: 
 **message: 'Cannot bulk load. The file "Screenshot_20190421-125051.png" does not exist.'**

**Special Notes:** 
1.the reason of the openrowset statement in SQL is because I have to use similar statement to insert images in SQL server, like such:

```
INSERT INTO myimages values (1, (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\Google Drive\Pictures\20190501_102004.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1))
```

2. ExecuteQuery works if I'm using numbers or text, but obviously not with images.

Comment: <form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`>??

Comment: Hi Ritesh, I was just adding that as you were typing that in, and now my app is just in a loading phase - no error messages but is not inserting anything. -- and it just timed out